# ERROR: subquery in FROM must have an alias

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa

I am struggling with this problem :

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: subquery in FROM
>   must have an alias   Indice : For example, FROM (SELECT ...) [AS] foo.
>   Position : 15

The query looks like this :

```
Query query = em.createQuery("select u from UserClass as u where u.id.id = :id")
```

The only tricky thing here I found here is the u.id.id, the UserClass class is using en EmbeddedId :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_USER")
public class UserClass implements {

    @EmbeddedId
    private UserClassPK id;

...

}
```

And here is the UserClassPK class :

```
@Embeddable
public class UserClassPK {

    @Column(name = "ID_UTILISATEUR")
    private String id;
}
```

Aside from that, I have no idea why this error is occuring.

Edit : Added the MyClassPK class. Also it was a bad choice from picking "User" as entity name for the example, I changed it to UserClass.

Comment: `u` is an alias of the table and `id.id` is the name of an attribute?

Comment: What is `u.id.id` ?  And `user` is a reserved word so it is a very poor choice for a table name.

Comment: I think you have completely messed up with the sql basics. Please check them on how to write a simple query with alias

Comment: are u sure that table and column names in the database are not case sensitive

Comment: Givven the HQL query I wouldn't expect the obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") to even generate a subquery. There must something wrong with the Hibernate configuration. You should turn on the logging of the generated SQL statements to see what Hibernate makes of that HQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution ! The problem came from the interpretation of `query.getSingleResult()` which generated a subquery.

I just had to change the dialect used by JPA, in src/main/resources/spring-jpa.xml :

```
<context:property-placeholder
        location="classpath*:jpa-postgresql.properties"
        ignore-unresolvable="true" />
```

With the jpa-postgresql.properties file :

```
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
jpa.dialect=org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect
jpa.vendor.adapter=HibernateJpaVendorAdapter
```